# i have a oracle table EMP columns are NAME,AGE,DEPT

Tags: sql, select

i have a oracle table EMP columns are NAME,AGE,DEPT.

now i want to retrive data from EMP using "select statement";

1. `Select Name, age, dept from Emp;`
2. `select Dept, age, emp from Emp;`

Which one will take less time to retrieve data?

Or will the retrieve time not be different?

Comment: If at least one of those columns are indexed, performance shouldn't be different between them.  This is also dependent on how many rows you have; obviously 5 or 6 rows will come back super quick, but 5 or 6 million rows will take a *while*, even with indices.

Comment: now ?? dept age name?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Makoto: indexes don't play a role here as now WHERE clause is involved. The DBMS will almost certainly scan the entire table without the use of an index (clustered indexes aside as they "are" essentially the table

Comment: okey... tks MAKO n hiorse.........1.Select Name, age, dept from Emp;
 2.select Dept, age, emp from Emp;
which one ll give better performance...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
Select Name, Age, Dept From EMP
```

Or
if you have only Three columns in your EMP table than you also use

```
Select * from EMP.
```

both take same time..

in your question your second query is time consuming because you use, two time dept column in it.

for Better performance you can create index on EMP Table.